# is there an open source commenting system available?

Tags: request, comments

I'd like to enable a commenting mechanism through the system, I've done some googling and found some SaaS like [disqus](http://disqus.com/) and [gentlesource](http://www.gentlesource.com/comment-script/) but I'm looking for more like self-hosted / open source apps. and I like to understand the architecture of such a systems in case I wanted to implement it myself.

Comment: what web technologies are you using? jsp, asp.net,... ?

Comment: wrong place to post this, SO is for programming questions, not web application requests.

Comment: java is not a web language! do you mean jsp?

Comment: @Jakub I guess this is a programming related question, I mentioned earlier that I like to understand the architecture of such a systems in case I wanted to implement it myself.

Comment: @AdelBoutros please consider seeing the definition of [java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)) and [jsp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.jsp) and my question is not a programming language specific. I need to know how to architect such a system and are there any open source systems doing this already?

Comment: all the libraries you have suggested are web oriented. If your language is not programming language specific, then why did you tag it as **java**??????

Answer (score 6):

Consider [juvia](https://github.com/phusion/juvia) `https://github.com/phusion/juvia` ;)

> Juvia is an open source commenting system. It allows you to outsource your commenting needs to an external system so that you don't have to build your own commenting system for each website or each web app. Embedding a Juvia commenting page only involves pasting a JavaScript snippet into your web page.

Comment: Juvia is the only system I can find that is what you're looking for.  I too am on the search for a system like this.

Comment: Yes I am also looking for some self hosted commenting system for Ghost blog hosted on my own server. Juvia developed is discontinued as informed by the developer, when I asked about integration with Ghost blog.